# Ubuntu cannot boot on Dell XPS13 after low battery

Tags: boot, uefi, dell

I have a Dell XPS13 that I bought with ubuntu on it, no other operative system.

Today it went off because it ran out of battery and when I turned it on I got a screen of Dell assistance saying "no bootable devies found".

I did all the diagnostics, of the system and of the BIOS and preboot and everything is fine.

I opened the BIOS setup and I played a bit around with the settings.
I switched off the secure boot, set the SATA operation to RAID On (AHCI doesn't see the hard drive at all) and tried both legacy and UEFI modes but I'm not succeding in finding the right setting.

Most importantly, at some point I noticed there was no "boot option" in the list for the boot sequence and I don't know how to restore the correct one for ubuntu.
If I create a new one, I have only one option as file system and I found only 3 .efi files in the folders I can access. One is \efi_factory\boot\bootx64.efi and another is grubx64.efi in the same directory.
With either of them if I boot I see first a screen with Dell recovery mode, then the ubuntu logo appearing and after a while just black shell interface with initramfs  saying "unable to find medium containing a live file system"

any idea of how can I fix this?

It's the computer I use for work and I have a lot of non-backed up stuff in it, so I cannot just reinstall ubuntu from scratch...

Thanks!
Ilaria

Comment: Try making a live USB with Ubuntu to see if you can still read the disk. Make sure to leave the BIOS set to AHCI if that’s what it originally was.